# no luck with javax timer with Jlabel

Tags: java, swing, timer, jlabel

I'm still having issues with updating the JLabel using a timer. I can't seem to figure out what I am missing. the global second variable stays at zero so I am guessing the timers working but not updating the GUI window?

```
 import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Globals 
{
    public static int seconds = 0;
}

class main
{
    public static void main(String Args[])
    {

        //text timeline = new text();
        JFrame testing = new JFrame();
        frame textdes = new frame();
        testing.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        testing.setSize(1000,1000);
        testing.setVisible(true);

        Countdown timer = new Countdown();
        Timer countdown = new Timer(5000, timer);
        countdown.start();

        JLabel countdowntext = new JLabel();
        countdowntext.setText("Now its :" + Globals.seconds);
        testing.add(countdowntext);     
        testing.add(textdes);

    }
}

class frame extends JFrame
{
    class Countdown implements ActionListener 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Globals.seconds++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the text of the label only once in the program. Then the timer changes the value of a variable, but doesn't do anything with the label. It should do:

```
Globals.seconds++;
countdowntext.setText("Now its :" + Globals.seconds);
```

Here's a complete example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Globals {
    public static int seconds = 0;
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String Args[]) {

        //text timeline = new text();
        JFrame testing = new JFrame();
        testing.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        testing.setSize(1000,1000);
        testing.setVisible(true);

        JLabel countDownLabel = new JLabel();
        countDownLabel.setText("Now it's : " + Globals.seconds);
        testing.add(countDownLabel);

        CountDown countdown = new CountDown(countDownLabel);
        Timer timer = new Timer(5000, countDown);
        timer.start();
    }
}

class CountDown implements ActionListener {
    private JLabel countDownLabel;

    public CountDown(JLabel countDownLabel) {
        this.countDownLabel = countDownLabel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Globals.seconds++;
        this.countDownLabel.setText("Now it's : " + Globals.seconds);
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried doing that earlier but it comes up with a error stating it cannot find the symbol

Comment: You have to pass the JLabel to update to your CountDown instance, as a constructor argument, so that the countdown can keep a reference to the label and update it every time it's called. You should also learn the Java naming conventions and avoid creating useless classes. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
public class MainFrame{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main frame");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel countdownText  = new JLabel();

    int seconds = 0;

    public MainFrame() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new Countdown());
        timer.start();

        panel.add(countdownText);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320,240));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        countdownText.setText("Now its :" + seconds);
    }

    class Countdown implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            seconds++;
            countdownText.setText("Now its :" + seconds);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```